# Show that $\frac{1}{x}$ is not integrable on $[0,1]$ - why we use fundamental theorem of calculus?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I found the followin proof that $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $[0,1]$:

$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}dx=\ln1-\ln 0=-\infty$$

But how can one employ here fundamental theorem of calculus?? $\frac{1}{x}$ is not continuous on $[0,1]$ because it sint even defined at $0$...

What about Riemann integral of this function on $[0,1]$

Can someone explain the whole thing to me? Thank you!

Comment: Where did you find this so-called proof?

Comment: In one polish book in my library. It was just written as I stated it.

Comment: It's not Riemann integrable since it's not bounded.

Comment: You should work on $(0,1)$, then it's fine. You just need to take one sided limits. Expressions like $\ln 0$ don't make sense.

Comment: $\int_0^1\frac1xdx$ is improper, and should be interpreted as $\lim_{a\to 0^+}\int_a^1\frac1xdx$.

Comment: And then i can use fundamental theorem of calculus...